# How to create the following HTML dynamically through javascript

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create the following HTML as shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/53/

```
<div data-role="panel" id="rightpanel" data-position="right" data-display="reveal" data-theme="b">
   <div class="tpMenuWrap">
      <a href="#demo-links" data-rel="close" class="icon-cancel-circled-1 panelCloseBtn"></a>
      <ul class="ul_menu">
         <li><a>My Recent Order</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="recentOrderslistWrap">
         <a href="#"><b>16/4/2015:</b> Vendor Name</a>
         <a href="#"><b>16/4/2015:</b> Vendor Name</a>
         <a href="#"><b>16/4/2015:</b> Vendor Name</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="btMenuWrap">
      <ul class="ul_menu">
         <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
         <li><a>Sign out</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried as followng as shown in this fiddle , but nothing is being displayed

http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/56/

```
$(document).on('click', '.rightpanelclass', function (e) {

    var rightpanelmaindiv = $('<div data-role="panel" id="rightpanel" data-position="right" data-display="reveal" data-theme="b">');

    var tpMenuWrap = $('   <div class="tpMenuWrap">');

    var html = '<a href="#demo-links" data-rel="close" class="icon-cancel-circled-1 panelCloseBtn"></a>';

    html += '<ul class="ul_menu">\
           <li><a>My Recent Order</a></li>\
             </ul>';

    tpMenuWrap.append(html);
    rightpanelmaindiv.append(tpMenuWrap);



    var recentOrderslistWrap = $('<div class="recentOrderslistWrap"></div>');

    var recentorders = '<a href="#"><b>16/4/2015:</b> Vendor Name</a>';

    recentorders += '<a href="#"><b>16/4/2015:</b> Vendor Name</a>';

    recentOrderslistWrap.append(recentorders);


    tpMenuWrap.append(recentOrderslistWrap);

    var btMenuWrap = $('<div class="btMenuWrap"></div>');

    var detailshtml = '<ul class="ul_menu">';

    detailshtml += '<li><a>Contact Us</a></li>';
    detailshtml += ' <li><a>Sign out</a></li>';
    detailshtml += '</ul>';

    btMenuWrap.append(detailshtml);

    rightpanelmaindiv.append(btMenuWrap);


    $("#rightpanel").html(rightpanelmaindiv);


    $("#rightpanel").trigger("create");




});
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this .

Comment: Its static HTML, can't you create a hidden div with above HTML and use it later

Comment: This entire thing can be put together as one HTML string, turn it into an DOM object and insert it.  I see no reason you are creating tiny pieces of DOM hieararchy and trying to glue them all together and then insert it.  Just make one big HTML string, set that as `.innerHTML` of a container object and be done.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/bisivemivu/1/#rightpanel. Check you code works fine!

Comment: Thank you , could you please post ur code in a fiddle , i don't know how to use jsbin .

Comment: You can edit it in right top. Here you have edit panel -> http://jsbin.com/bisivemivu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, you have two divs with id = "rightpanel".

Remove the static one for now (in the html box), and also change one of the last lines from:

```
$("#rightpanel").html(rightpanelmaindiv);
```

to..

```
$("body").html(rightpanelmaindiv);
```

Obviously you could use a wrapper-div instead, but that's up to you.